# React Redux toolkit: type is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<type, { payload: any; type: string; }>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

Github link: https://github.com/safiullah7/legan
Branch: Redux

In my slice file, I have initial state of type IHome:

```
export interface IHome {
  bannerContent: IBannerContent,
  expertiseContent: IExpertiseContent,
  industryExpertise: IIndustryContent
}
```

When I update the bannerContent:IBannerContent in the view after taking user input, I'm trying to pass the updated object to the function "updateHomeContent" I get the compiler error:

```
Type 'IBannerContent' is not assignable to type 'void | IHome | WritableDraft<IHome>'.
```

here is my slice file:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IHome } from '../../models/home';
import { RootState } from '../../store';

const initialState: IHome = {
   bannerContent: {
       heading: 'Legal asdad',
       mainText: 'The asdasdasdasd',
       bottomText: 'You can asdadsad you shortly',
   },
   expertiseContent: {
       heading: 'LEGAL asdsad',
       mainText: 'Our niche is solutions.',
       contentList: [
           {
           heading: 'DATA',
           subHeading: 'GDPR ',
           panel: 'panel1',
           icon: 'rocket',
           list: [
               'GDPR',
               'International',
               'Privacy',
               'Data',
               'Compliance',
               'Canada',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'TECH CONTRACTS',
           subHeading: 'EULA',
           panel: 'panel2',
           icon: 'world',
           list: [
               'GDPR',
               'International',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY',
           subHeading: 'Trademark',
           panel: 'panel3',
           icon: 'intellectual',
           list: [
               'GDPR end-to-end compliance (Data mapping)',
               'International transfers of perso'
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'INTERNET LAW',
           subHeading: 'Website Take-Downs | DMCA | UDRP',
           panel: 'panel4',
           icon: 'rocket2',
           list: [
               'GDPR end-to',
           ],
           },
       ]
   },
   industryExpertise: {
       heading: 'INDUSTRY EXPERTISE',
       mainText: 'Our sindustries.',
       contentList: [
           {
           heading: 'SOFTWARE',
           id: 0,
           list: [
               'Lorem',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'MOBILE APPs',
           id: 1,
           list: [
               'voluptas illum ',
               'Lorem ipsum illum ',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'START-UPs',
           id: 2,
           list: [
               'Lorem illum ',
               'Lorem ipsum illum',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'E-COMMERCE',
           id: 3,
           list: [
               'Lorem illum ',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'VIDEO GAMING',
           id: 4,
           list: [
               'Lorem illum ',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'ARTIFICIAL INTELLIGENCE',
           id: 5,
           list: [
               'Lorem illum ',
           ],
           },
           {
           heading: 'BLOCKCHAIN',
           id: 6,
           list: [
               'Lorem illum ',
           ],
           },
       ]
   }
};

const homeSlice = createSlice({
   name: 'home',
   initialState,
   reducers: {
       updateHomeContent: (state, action: PayloadAction<IBannerContent>) => {
           return action.payload;
       }
   }
});

export const { updateHomeContent } = homeSlice.actions;

export const getHomeContentSelector = (state: RootState) => state.homeSlice;

export default homeSlice.reducer;
```

here is my store.ts file:

```
import homeSlice from './features/home/home.slice';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        homeSlice
    }
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

here is my store.hooks.ts file:

```
import {TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

I'm new to redux toolkit and I would appreciate your help and concept clearance. Also, if there are better ways to do what I want to do,, please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `return action.payload` would replace that whole slice. But it seems you only want to update `state.bannerContent`.

```js
   reducers: {
       updateHomeContent: (state, action: PayloadAction<IBannerContent>) => {
           state.bannerContent = action.payload;
       }
```

Comment: actually, its giving me compiler error on "PayloadAction<IBannerContent>) in the method argument you written in your reply. I'll write the error here again:
`Type 'IBannerContent' is not assignable to type 'void | IHome | WritableDraft<IHome>'.
      Type 'IBannerContent' is missing the following properties from type 'WritableDraft<IHome>': bannerContent, expertiseContent, industryExpertise
`

Comment: Sorry, I acidentally copied over your `resturn` statement, of course that should not be there

Comment: Any idea about the solution? @phry

Comment: Yes. You take the updated code I posted above.

Comment: Way to go! Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: I am not a React expert but isn't it that redux recommend that you never make changes directly in the reducer and actually return the new state?

Comment: @targhs That is true for hand-written legacy Redux reducers. But if you use the (since 2019) officially recommended Redux Toolkit and the `createSlice` function, it is preferred to mutate the `state` object within the slices case reducers. You can read up on modern Redux [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).

Comment: thanks @phry for updating my obsolete knowledge.